# write newline into a file

Tags: java, file, newline

considering the following function

```
private static void GetText(String nodeValue) throws IOException {

   if(!file3.exists()) {
       file3.createNewFile();
   }

   FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(file3,true);
   if(nodeValue!=null)
       fop.write(nodeValue.getBytes());

   fop.flush();
   fop.close();

}
```

what to add to make it to write each time in the next line?

for example i want each words of a given string in a seperate lline for example:

```
i am mostafa
```

writes as:

```
 i
 am
 mostafa
```

Comment: You can remove the `f.exists()/f.createNewFile()` stuff. `new FileOutputStream()` already does that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To write text (rather than raw bytes) to a file you should consider using [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). You should also wrap it in a [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) which will then give you the [newLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) method.

To write each word on a new line, use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to break your text into an array of words.

So here's a simple test of your requirement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String nodeValue = "i am mostafa";

    // you want to output to file
    // BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file3, true));
    // but let's print to console while debugging
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

    String[] words = nodeValue.split(" ");
    for (String word: words) {
        writer.write(word);
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

The output is:

```
i
am
mostafa
```

Comment: but the point is i want it to write each byes of the string in a new line not each string ...did you get what i mean?

Comment: You want each byte on a new line? If so, please make it clear in your question.

Comment: i did it just now, sorry for that

Comment: but it gives same result as my function in the question :( oh ~

Comment: I think you must be missing something. See full example in updated answer.

Comment: oh, now its working...on the debugging window but when i use to write into a file and them open it, its not like in the debugging window, why is that so?

Comment: oh, now its working...on the debugging window but when i use to write into a file and them open it, its not like in the debugging window, why is that so?

Comment: When I use the code above and write to file (use the commented writer), I see the exact same output as above in the file. Are you possibly executing Java on a Unix platform (so getting unix line feeds) and viewing the file with a Windows editor (like Notepad). That would explain why you don't see line feeds in the file.

Comment: you may laugh but i think from beginning you were right! when i send it to the debugging window it shows them in new line but in the file they are followed in same line! why is it like this? i tried noepad,wordpad and office word but all 3 never shows them as they appears in the debugging window O_o

Comment: no, im using windows vista! ooh what you use to viweing them?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5819/discussion-between-sudocode-and-mostafa)

Answer (score 13):

Change the lines

```
if(nodeValue!=null)
    fop.write(nodeValue.getBytes());

fop.flush();
```

to

```
if(nodeValue!=null) {
    fop.write(nodeValue.getBytes());
    fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
}

fop.flush();
```

**Update to address your edit**:

In order to write each word on a different line, you need to split up your input string and then write each word separately.

```
private static void GetText(String nodeValue) throws IOException {

    if(!file3.exists()) {
        file3.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(file3,true);
    if(nodeValue!=null)
        for(final String s : nodeValue.split(" ")){
            fop.write(s.getBytes());
            fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        }
    }

    fop.flush();
    fop.close();

}
```

Comment: @Mostafa What program are you using to view the file?  Also, are you using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`? (I edited my answer.)

Comment: @Mostafa Are you writing `"\n".getBytes()` or `System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes()`?

Comment: with wordpad and office word still showing same answer as notpad shows

Comment: result is same, did you realized you declared **s** but actually didnt use it

Comment: @Mostafa Oops. That was a mistake. I've fixed it.

Comment: you may laugh but i think from beginning you were right! when i send it to the debugging window it shows them in new line but in the file they are followed in same line! why is it like this? i tried noepad,wordpad and office word but all 3 never shows them as they appears in the debugging window O_o

Comment: @lonesome: newline character in Linux is "\n". windows is  "\r\n". if you try in windows. Please try "\r\n".getBytes()

Comment: You can also use `System.lineSeparator()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
Files.write(Paths.get(filepath),texttobewrittentofile,StandardOpenOption.APPEND ,StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

This creates a file, if it does not exist
If files exists, it is uses the existing file and text is appended
If you want everyline to be written to the next line add lineSepartor for newline into file.

```
String texttobewrittentofile = text + System.lineSeparator();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!file3.exists()){
    file3.createNewFile();
}
FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(file3,true);
if(nodeValue!=null) fop.write(nodeValue.getBytes());

fop.write("\n".getBytes());

fop.flush();
fop.close();
```

You need to add a newline at the end of each write.

Comment: If you're using windows it would be "\r\n" for a new line.

Comment: @OlleSöderström you should've write this solution as an answer! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use something like the following. Pay attention to "\n":

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 3/26/16.
 */
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
public class FileExample {


    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        File newFile = new File("tweet.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(newFile);
        fileWriter.write("Mona Jalal");
        fileWriter.append("\nMona Mona");
        fileWriter.close();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(newFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        fileReader.close();
        bufferedReader.close();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

in WINDOWS you should write `"\r\n"` for a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You could print through a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fop);
ps.println(nodeValue);
ps.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

the other answers should work. however I wanna mention

from java doc:

> **FileWriter** is meant for writing streams of characters. For writing
>   streams of raw bytes, consider using a **FileOutputStream**.

reading your method codes, you are about to write String to the file, what you were doing is convert String to raw bytes, then write so I think using FileWriter is not a bad idea.

And for the newline problem, Writer has method .write(String), which is convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

just use \r\n for endline if you are using windows operating system.

Comment: I don't see how this can be better than `System.lineSeparator()` or `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.