# How to save string in one line?

Tags: java, android, string, io

I have several strings: a,b,c,d,e. I want to save them to file FILENAME as a single string
`a b c d:e`. The problem - i need to keep information that `d;e` starts on new line.

```
String str = a
        + " "
        + b

        + c
        + "\n "
        + d
        + ";"
        + e + "\r\n";
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    fos.write(str.getBytes());
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491687/write-newline-into-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I probably understand your question.  Your question is given an input string with format `"%s %s %s\n%s:%s\n"`, how do I store them in the format `"%s %s %s %s:%s"` in a file, and I think you know how to do the second part.

In the first part, you need to parse the input string to allow you to get the five elements.  One simple way is to use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function which returns an array of strings given an input string and delimiters described as an regular expression:

```
String[]    String.split(String regex)
// Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
```

For example, in your case is:

```
String[] elements = str.split("[ ;\n\r]");
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) is more information about the regular expression.

If you don't really care about what elements inside the input string and just simply remove new line symbols, then you can use [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

In your case, it would be:

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
```

again, its first input argument is an regular expression.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) (if you're familiar with C/C++, this one is similar to `printf()`).  For example, the following gives you the string format you want:

```
String.format("%s %s %s%n%s;%s%n", a, b, c, d, e);
```

where %n is the new line symbol.

If you output string is long, then you can also use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) along with the `String.format()`.

Comment: Now i;ve done it in this way, but it is still saved as 2 lines in a file, while i need one.