# Printing a Hashset of Strings on seperate lines

Tags: java, newline, hashset

I've read in a txt file into Arraylist to format it and then that list into a Hashset to remove duplicates. When I try and write to a txt file it puts all values on one line. If I try to write the ArrayList to a txt file, it seperates the lines. Any help welcome

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 String filename = "data.txt";
 String filename_out = "output.txt";
 boolean dataRead;
 ArrayList<String> textFile = new ArrayList<String>();

try{

         Scanner datafile = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));

        while(datafile.hasNext()) {
            //Scanner readIn = new Scanner(datafile.next());//.useDelimiter("[,;:.!? ]") ;

            textFile.add (datafile.next().replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d","").toLowerCase().trim()); //reads next line, removes punctuation, sets to lowercase

    }

   // Collections.sort(textFile); // sort into alphabetical order
    datafile.close();
    dataRead = true;

}
 catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(textFile);
for (String eachString : s)
{
    dictionary.add(eachString);
}
Collections.sort(dictionary);
//System.out.println(dictionary);

try{
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename_out);
Writer output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
int listSize = dictionary.size();
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
    output.write(dictionary.get(i).toString()+ "\n"); //this is where i think the problem is
}

output.close();
    } 
     catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }        

}
```

Comment: i think this answer should help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8491808/728610

Comment: @ArvindSridharan: when you see a question that is already answered please flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: oh right. i have flagged it now.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses `\r\n`

so change

```
output.write(dictionary.get(i).toString()+ "\n");
```

to

```
output.write(dictionary.get(i).toString()+ "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make output a BufferedWriter and use its newLine() method.

```
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fw);

...
output.write(dictionary.get(i).toString());
output.newLine();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
output.write(dictionary.get(i).toString()+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```