# New Line while writing into file

Tags: java, filewriter

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491687/write-newline-into-a-file) link and I came up with below code

```
     try {
        File file = new File(
                "C:/dataset.txt");

        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        List<Integer> data = generateData(args);

        // one per line
        for (final int i : data) {
            bw.write(i);
            bw.newLine(); // Here it throws NullPointerException
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
```

**NOTE:** Even if I move `bw.newLine();` before `for` loop, it throws `NullPointerException`.

Image

[image]

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Are you sure it throws a NullPointerException ?

Comment: Yes I have attached the picture. See updated question.

Comment: Are you sure that the `bw.newLine();` is the one that is throwing the exception?

Comment: `newLine` will `write` what is returned by `System.getProperty("line.separator")` plus will try to get its length. If no such system property exists (by explicitly doing a `clearProperty`?) that will throw a NPE.

Comment: @orique `System.getProperty("line.separator")` returns `null`

Comment: I have a suspicion something with your setup is wrong or misplaced if System.getProperty is null. That could likewise also be causing your other error.

Answer (score 1):

To add a line seperator you could use this.

```
    //to add a new line after each value added to File
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

and then call it like so:

```
    bw.write(newLine);
```

EDIT:
since you cant use a System.getProperty with a BufferWriter I would suggest the code below:

```
private FileOutputStream fOut;
private OutputStreamWriter writer;
fOut = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
writer.append(.... whatever you wish to append ...);
writer.append(separator);
writer.flush();
fOut.close();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `System.getProperty("line.separator")` returns `null`.

Comment: The `write` implementation does a `.length()` on the parameter so it will throw a NPE. This system property shouldn't be null...

Comment: Please look at the edited part! I updated the code based on what @orique said :D